# How to use templateUrl from remote server? Angular 2

Tags: templates, angular, ionic2

I have file with this component with remote URL:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: '/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/tabs'
})
export class TabsPage {
}
```

And my compiler gave me:

```
[13:28:50]  Error reading template file, "/mobilesiteapp/template/?path=pages/tabs": Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\denwerready\-readyscript
\modules\mobilesiteapp\appsourse\src\pages\mobilesiteapp\template\?path=pages/tabs'
```

I don't need this check because I need to get templates from url.

How to fix it? Do anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your usecase?

Using remote templates is not possible, you have to have a local copy of the template to have Angular 2 compiler work correctly.

Optionally, you could use `ComponentFactoryResolver` and inject a template/component dynamically from your controller.

https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/

Comment: I use Ionic app within my php server application. The templates that I build, which compiler make, is in the same directory that it must to be.
appsourse
---src
---- templates
---www
---- build - folder with compiled template.

I need, to get template from url because I use my variales from php in it, that contains data and I check auth in my phpapplication(I need it only on server). PHP answers me builded templates with information from my php variables. That's why I need it.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: /mobilesiteapp/template/ - is URL to get my checks and retrieve me PHP compiled template.
?path=pages/tabs - What template I need to compile in PHP.

The Angular compiler compile to me template with php variables. PHP compiler(Smarty) compile me the the PHP variables in compiled template.

Comment: I only need the compiled template. But than app is appear the query goes to my server which make some operations, and retrieve me template.